# How to type a variable that implements a function interface that takes a generic?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm sure this is a dupe but for the life of me can't find it. I have a function interface that takes a type parameter:

```js
interface A<T> {
    (foo: T): void
}
```

And I want to assign an arrow function that satisfies that interface to a variable:

```js
const x: A = <T>(foo: T) => { console.log(foo) };
```

But this of course fails to compile, because A requires the type parameter. This also fails:

```js
const x: A<T> = <T>(foo: T) => { console.log(foo) };
```

because the type variable `T` is not in scope on the LH of the assignment. How do I actually declare this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=51&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIB4AqA+ZBvAKGQAoYB7MgLmUwEpqA3M4AEwIF8CCEyQBnMMgAe1VMgC8yLABpspCtToTceZD35kANhAB0msgHN5ZWsnYBuAkA)

Comment: Your interface isn't done properly. Here's one I made on the playground. [Solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=57#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYBVwQDwoHxQLxQAUAZgPakBcUKAlPrgG6kCWAJgNwBQnSpCAzsCgAPKvGRpIGQQCdmCAOa4CJcnTy4A3rwGkANhAB0e0gtWkaAX3ZA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generic type, which includes a function that uses the generic parameter:

```
interface A<T> { (foo: T): void }
```

This is a non generic type that includes a generic function:

```
interface A { <T>(foo: T): void }
```

You want this one.

The key here is that `A` does not enforce any type for `T`. That is done when the function is *called*, which is why it needs to to be on the function declaration, and not the interface or type alias.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QHgBUA+AChgHsKAuZQgSloDcLgATLAXyywQpADOYZAA9a6ALwFCAGjKUadesgnFMyPoIoAbCADptFAObkqyzgG4sQA)

---

And personally, I think this will be much clearer if you use `type` instead of `interface`.

```
type A = <T>(foo: T) => void
```

Comment: Thanks that got it. I agree with you about type vs interface, but my team feels differently so... yeah.